# Renaming columns using numbers from a range in python/pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm stuck with the following situation.  I'm pretty sure I'm missing something simple, but I tried a lot of suggestions here and at other sites, and haven't found what I'm looking for.

I have a dataframe with a lot of randomly named columns (courtesy of provided csv file).  I would like to rename these columns using digits from the range function.

Since I'm renaming all columns, I could do it directly using

```
df.columns = [str(x) for x in range(1,2000)]
```

However, hypothetically, could I do it through the rename() function?  Maybe using a lambda?  I have tried many different variations, but I'm getting all sorts of errors.
    I'm looking for the syntax to give me the equivalent of

```
 df.rename(columns= (str(x) for x in range(1,2000)))
```

where rename assigns the name to the columns sequentially based on the given range.
The above does't work.  But is there a way to make it work?

Thank you!

Comment: What sort of errors?

Comment: @Craig this particular attempt gave me TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable

Comment: The answer from @bernie will fix that. The documentation for `DataFrame.rename()` says that passing a list to rename is only valid for Series objects.

Comment: I realized it needed a dict, but was having trouble coming up with proper way of creating it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can pass a `dict` to rename's `columns` kwarg:

```
df.rename(columns={x:y for x,y in zip(df.columns,range(0,len(df.columns)))})
```

That will take:

```
>>> df
   ID1  ID2 POS1 POS2     TYPE TYPEVAL
1    A  001    1    5    COLOR     RED
2    A  001    1    5   WEIGHT    50KG
3    A  001    1    5   HEIGHT   160CM
4    A  002    6   19   FUTURE     YES
5    A  002    6   19  PRESENT      NO
6    B  001   26   34   COLOUR    BLUE
7    B  001   26   34   WEIGHT    85KG
8    B  001   26   34   HEIGHT   120CM
9    C  001   10   13   MOBILE   NOKIA
10   C  001   10   13   TABLET    ASUS
```

And give you:

```
>>> df.rename(columns={x:y for x,y in zip(df.columns,range(0,len(df.columns)))})
    0    1   2   3        4      5
1   A  001   1   5    COLOR    RED
2   A  001   1   5   WEIGHT   50KG
3   A  001   1   5   HEIGHT  160CM
4   A  002   6  19   FUTURE    YES
5   A  002   6  19  PRESENT     NO
6   B  001  26  34   COLOUR   BLUE
7   B  001  26  34   WEIGHT   85KG
8   B  001  26  34   HEIGHT  120CM
9   C  001  10  13   MOBILE  NOKIA
10  C  001  10  13   TABLET   ASUS
```

Comment: This is awesome.  However, please, clarify something for me.  When I run your code in it's own line (assignment) - it works as expected.  However, when I chain it after dropping the first few columns, I get starting index as 4, not 0.  It seems that what's happening is that this column renaming happens before the columns are dropped.  But I would think that it should drop the columns first, and then rename.  Thank you.

Comment: The problem is that the value of `df.columns` in the `zip(...)` is coming from the original dataframe before the columns are dropped.

Comment: Here's a different approach that might work for you. After dropping the columns, transpose the dataframe, create a new numeric index, transpose is back, and then convert it to strings. See if this code works for you: `df.drop(...).T.reset_index(drop=True).T.rename(columns=str)`

Comment: Nice idea, @Craig!

Comment: @Craig, so (for future references), one cannot chain calls that rely on changing values of column/index names? Very newbie question.    Also, your idea with transposing is really good and is chainable.  Except it will only work if integral column names need to start with 0.  The solution provided by bernie is more generic.  But not chainable...

Comment: I'm still learning too. As I understand it, you can change the names (for example via the dictionary method) if you created the dictionary prior to the chain. The problem is that, the dataframe named `df` is the original one until the entire chain has been executed and the assignment occurs. The intermediate values at each step of the chain are just passed to the next method in the chain. In the middle of the chain `df` can only refer to the original values in the dataframe. Often this isn't a problem unless you are changing the structure of the frame (ie dropping columns) in the chain.

Comment: I think that the `.pipe()` method is the solution. It takes a function and passes the dataframe to the function allowing you to modify the intermediate dataframe. This seems to work for my test code: `df.drop(...).pipe(lambda d: d.rename(columns=dict(zip(d.columns, range(len(d.columns))))))`

Comment: **Doesn't work.**  If the column names are an assortment of datatypes like int, string or objects.  The named column won't be found in your little dictionary and thus the columns won't be renamed, and worse, it won't be renamed and there won't be an error.  Downvote.

Answer (score 8):

If you just want to rename the columns using numbers, this is probably the easiest way to do it:

```
df.columns = np.arange(len(df.columns))
#-- or --
df.columns = [x for x in range(0, len(df.columns))]
```

**Demo:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a', 'b', 'c'], 'B': ['d','e','f'], 'C': ['g','h','i']})
print(df)
   A  B  C
0  a  d  g
1  b  e  h
2  c  f  i
```

Renaming the columns:

```
df.columns = np.arange(len(df.columns))
print(df)
   0  1  2
0  a  d  g
1  b  e  h
2  c  f  i
```

Comment: clean and simple

Answer (score -2):

```
df.columns = range(len(df.columns))
```

Comment: Please explain your code. Code only answers are not recommended.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35224335)